# Ubuntu has No Sound

Tags: sound

i am using ubuntu via wubi. i don't hear a single noise or sound, no matter i am playing a song or video. how should i fix it? thz

I have already installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras and Flash, as well as all available updates, but it still doesn't give me a single sound, what should i do?

is there any sound drive i have to install just like win7? 
and how could i find the drive?

I am using an Acer 4830 notebook with win7. 
certainly, my nb has on board sound card.

My ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you probably need to install a driver.  But first, click on the sound icon at the top right, it looks like a speaker with sound coming out (might be right or left click).  Then open the sound settings and look under hardware to see if Ubuntu recognizes your sound card.  If nothing is there under hardware, you will need a driver.  If something is there, check the output tab to make sure the sound is not muted.

For more help, pls tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using and also more about your computer. Sound card may be part of the mother board or may be an additional card, in a lappy probably on-board the motherboard.

Comment: i am using 12.04 lts version via wubi, my nb is acer 4830 
if i hv to install a sound drive, what drive should i install??